# Is this the correct use of 'restrict' in C?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

Currently I'm learning about parallel programming. I have the following loop that needs to be parallelized.

```
for(i=0; i<n/2; i++)
   a[i] = a[i+1] + a[2*i]
```

If I run this sequentially there is no problem, but if I want to run this in parallel, there occurs data recurrence. To avoid this I want to store the information to 'read' in a seperate variable e.g b.

So then the code would be:

```
b = a;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
for(i=0; i<n/2; i++)
  a[i] = b[i+1] + b[2*i];
```

But here comes the part I where I begin to doubt. Probably the variable b will point to the same memory location as a. So the second code block will do exactly as the first code block. Including recurrence I'm trying to avoid.

I tried something with * restric {variable}. Unfortunately I can't really find the right documentation.

My question:

**Do I avoid data recurrence by writing the code as follows?**

```
int *restrict b;
int *restrict a;
b = a;

#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
for(i=0; i<n/2; i++)
   a[i] = b[i+1] + b[2*i];
```

If not, what is a correct way to achieve this goal?

Thanks,
Ter

Comment: Your code violates the restrict requirement. It is not safe.  You'd have to.make a separately allocated copy of the array to be safe.

Comment: Yes! How should I do that? What is the restrict requirement? @jonathanleffler

Comment: The definition of restrict says that if you have, within the same scope, two `restrict` pointers `a` and `b` then they *never* modify/access the *same* objects. Your code modifies/accesses the same objects, just not in the same iteration, excepting `i=0`

Comment: Thanks @anttiHaapala! How do i make separately allocated copy of the array?  If a en b cannot modify/acess the same objects. How would you edit the code?

Comment: `int *b = malloc(n * size of(*b)); …error check…; memmove(b, a, n *sizeof(*b)); …loop… free(b);`

Comment: memcpy instead of memmove :P As they're supposed to be separate...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala — I always use `memmove()` because it can't go wrong, but `memcpy()` is a defensible choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your proposed code:

```
int *restrict b;
int *restrict a;
b = a;
```

the assignment of `a` to `b` violates the `restrict` requirement. That requires that `a` and `b` do not point to the same memory, yet they clearly *do* point to the same memory.
It is not safe.

You'd have to.make a separately allocated copy of the array to be safe.  You could do that with:

```
int *b = malloc(n * size of(*b));
…error check…;
memmove(b, a, n *sizeof(*b));
…revised loop using a and b…
free(b);
```

I always use `memmove()` because it is always correct, dealing with overlapping copies.  In this case, it would be legitimate to use `memcpy()` because the space allocated for `b` will be separate from the space for `a`.  The system would be broken if the newly allocated space for `b` overlaps with `a` at all, assuming the pointer to `a` is valid.  If there was an overlap, the trouble would be that `a` was allocated and freed — so `a` is a dangling pointer pointing to released memory (and should not be being used at all), and `b` was coincidentally allocated where the old `a` was previously allocated. On the whole, it's not a problem worth worrying about.  (Using `memmove()` doesn't help if `a` is a dangling pointer, but it is always safe if given valid pointers, even if the areas of memory overlap.)